# Cannot connect to firebase database from webapp with python.

Tags: python-3.x, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I have a python web app.When I try to connect to the firebase with firebase admin I get error.This is how I tried to connect.

```
from firebase_admin import db
ref = db.reference('server/data')
```

And the error i get is

```
'string.'.format(url))
ValueError: Invalid databaseURL option: "None". databaseURL must be a non-empty URL string.
```

How can someone tell me how to do this correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error tells you forgot to initialize the Firebase SDK as the dataBaseURL is not set, have a look here how to do the initialization:

https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/07/accessing-database-from-python-admin-sdk.html

From there:

> ```
> import firebase_admin
> from firebase_admin import credentials
>
> cred = credentials.Cert('path/to/serviceKey.json')
> firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
>     'databaseURL' : 'https://my-db.firebaseio.com'
> })
> ```